# Why does calling .to_string() on a String avoid a move error? Isn't it a no-op?

Tags: rust, borrow

The following test program would not compile:

```
fn f1( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn f2( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    f1( my_string );
    f2( my_string );
}
```

It generates the well-expected error:

```
11 |     f1( my_string );
   |         --------- value moved here
12 |     f2( my_string );
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

However, if you treat `my_string` with the `to_string()` method, the program compiles and works. `to_string()` should be a no-op method since `my_string` is a `String` already. However, this programs works fine.

```
fn f1( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn f2( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    f1( my_string.to_string() );
    f2( my_string.to_string() );
}
```

How does the rust theory explain this paradox?

Comment: Passing `my_string` by value moves it. Calling `my_string.to_string()` only borrows the string and returns a different string as a copy.

Comment: @alter_igel: thank you. Yes, it must be correct because I can replace ```to_string()``` with ```clone()``` and get the same effect.  Why you don't make it the answer so I will accept it. Add a comment that  ```to_string()``` and ```clone()``` are equivalent in this case?

Comment: @kmdreko: thank you. This tittle is a lot better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`ToString::to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) method requires a `&str`, which is `Copy`, therefore it can be moved out while keeping ownership (because `&T: Copy` for `T: ?Sized`, see [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations-1)).

On the other hand, `String` does not implement `Copy`, which means once the value is moved, its ownership has been given away.

Comment: Essentially, `to_string()` for `String` is the same as calling `clone()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that `to_string()` applied to a `String` is not a no-op; it is equivalent to `clone()`. The clone returned by `to_string()` is moved, whereas the original `String` is only borrowed for cloning and is never moved.

I approve jthulhu's answer even though I'm not sure it points out the actual reason for the behavior.