# Why does .clone() not prevent a move when used in a closure?

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

I'm attempting to optimize an application through smart cloning and borrowing, and I'm observing the following behavior. The program below wouldn't work:

```
fn f( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    f( my_string );
    f( my_string );
}
```

It generates the well-known *"used after move"* error.

```
7 |     f( my_string );
  |        --------- value moved here
8 |     f( my_string );
  |        ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

This can be solved by cloning `my_string`. The program below works fine:

```
fn f( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    f( my_string.clone() );
    f( my_string.clone() );
}
```

However, if you use the same approach in a multi-threaded environment, cloning doesn't help any longer. When the function calls are embedded in threads:

```
use std::thread;

fn f( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    thread::spawn( move || { f( my_string.clone() ); } );
    thread::spawn( move || { f( my_string.clone() ); } );
}
```

the program generates the *"used after move"* error again:

```
10 |     thread::spawn( move || { f( my_string.clone() ); } );
   |                    ^^^^^^^      --------- use occurs due to use in closure
   |                    |
   |                    value used here after move
```

However, you can remedy this by moving the thread into the function, with the same net effect:

```
use std::thread;

fn f( string: String) {
    thread::spawn( move || { println!("{}", string ); } );
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    f( my_string.clone() );
    f( my_string.clone() );
}
```

The above program works fine. Or, if you prefer, you can clone `my_string` in advance and use the clone in the *second* function call:

```
use std::thread;

fn f( string: String) {
    println!("{}", string );
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    let my_second_string: String = my_string.clone();

    thread::spawn( move || { f( my_string.clone() ); } );
    thread::spawn( move || { f( my_second_string ); } );
}
```

It looks a little like trial and error, but some theory can perhaps explain it.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814674/why-does-calling-to-string-on-a-string-avoid-a-move-error-isnt-it-a-no-op) regarding the *"used after move"* error. The other question discusses the effect of `to_string()`, while this one discusses `clone()` in a threaded environment.

Comment: It has become more or less idiomatic to write the `clone/move` idiom this way: `thread::spawn({ let my_string = my_string.clone(); move || { f( my_string ); } });`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, if you use the same approach in a multi-threaded environment, cloning doesn't help any longer. [...] It looks a little like trial and error, but some theory can perhaps explain it.

It does help if you do it right. The problem here is that a `move` closure means the value gets moved into the closure *before the closure runs*<sup>1</sup>.

So when you write

```
    thread::spawn(move || { f( my_string.clone()); });
```

what happens is

1. create the closure, move `my_string` inside the closure
2. spawn the thread
3. clone `my_string`
4. call f with the clone

By the time you're cloning `my_string` it's already way too late, because it's been moved from the outer function to the inside the closure and thread. It's as if you'd try to fix the original snippet by changing the contents of `f` thus:

```rust
fn f(string: String) {
    println!("{}", string.clone());
}

fn main() {
    let my_string = "ABCDE".to_string();
    f(my_string);
    f(my_string);
}
```

That obviously doesn't fix anything.

The usual solution for this is the so-called "precise capture pattern". "Capture clause" comes from C++ where it's a native feature, but in Rust it's not. What you do is that instead of creating a closure directly, you create and return the closure from a block, and before creating and returning the closure you can create a bunch of bindings which then get moved into the closure. It essentially provides a "closure setup" which is isolated:

```
thread::spawn({
    // shadow the outer `my_string` with a clone of itself
    let my_string = my_string.clone();
    // then move the clone into the closure
    move || { f(my_string); }
});
```

Incidentally an other option if you don't need to modify the `String` is to just put it in an `Arc`. Though you still need to clone outside the closure and move *the arc* inside the closure. The advantage is that cloning an arc just increments its refcount, it's atomic so it's not free, but it *can* be cheaper than cloning a complex / expensive object.

---

[1]: technically that can also happen with non-move closures, more precisely `move` closure will `move` (/ `copy`) everything it refers to, while a non-move closure may move or just borrow depending how the item is being used.

Answer (score 3):

The `move` keyword means that Rust now has to move all used variables from outside into the closure.
So by using `my_string` inside of `move || {}` you moved it in. If you just want to use a reference inside of the closure you can borrow outside the closure:

```rust
fn f(string: String) {
    println!("{}", string);
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    {
        // Take the reference outside of the `move`
        // closures so only the reference but not the
        // actual string gets moved inside.
        //
        // Since shared references are `Copy` they get
        // copied instead and you can reuse them.
        let my_string: &String = &my_string;
        let a = move || {
            f(my_string.clone());
        };
        let b = move || {
            f(my_string.clone());
        };
    }
}
```

But because you want to use it in a different thread wihch might outlive the current function the reference would have to be `'static`.

So to avoid moving `my_string` into the closure which gets passed to another thread you have to do the `clone` outside of the closure.

```rust
fn f(string: String) {
    println!("{}", string);
}

fn main() {
    let my_string: String = "ABCDE".to_string();
    {
        let my_string = my_string.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            f(my_string);
        });
    }
    {
        let my_string = my_string.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            f(my_string);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a very good and quite sufficient answer, but I've decided to approve Masklinn's answer because it contains more details and provides a different solution from the one I've found myself.

Comment: The first code snippet is irrelevant to this issue. You are using a ```&str``` as an argument and ```&str``` is not subject to moving. You can have many ```move || f(my_string)``` without cloning and/or many ```f(my_string)``` without cloning, and you never get the "used after move" error. In this case, using ```clone()``` is pointless.

Comment: That's the point of the first snippet. You take the reference so you only move (or more specifically copy) references inside the `move` closures. Btw there are no `&str` anywhere. The type of `my_string` inside of the block is `&String` similar but slightly different from `&str`. I've edited the answer to make it more clear. @KalleSvensson